# Issues with using test_and_set_bit function in linux

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, multiprocessing, atomic

I am trying to implement a spin lock using the test_and_set_bit function. I found a bitops.h file which consisted of this function. However, in my current kernel version which is 3.0, the function is not included in that header file i.e, bitops.h. Any anyone provide some references where I can find that?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I totally understand your question, but including `<linux/bitops.h>` should bring in the definition of `test_and_set_bit()`.  The actual definition of the function is not in `include/linux/bitops.h` but it is picked up via the include of `<asm/bitops.h>` that is in the `linux/` version of the include.

So to see the actual definition of `test_and_set_bit()` you can look in `arch/arm/include/asm/bitops.h` or `arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h` (or whatever other architecture you're interested in).

By the way, there's no reason to need to implement your own spinlock -- the kernel has (of course) the standard `spinlock_t` and also functions like `bit_spin_lock()` that use a single bit as a lock.

Comment: I could see that it is defined in arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h. However, I am having a hard time trying to get it to compile. It throws a lot of errors when I try to include linux/bitops.h and then try to compile it. Can you give me an example of how to use it?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to implement spinlock for my application where there are certain variables accessed by threads and to implement concurrency safely, I need it

Comment: So are you trying to use bitops.h from userspace?  If so yes it is tricky to get it to build outside of the kernel build system.  Also is there something wrong with pthread_spin_lock() etc?

Comment: Actually, I am using processes to do the rather than individual threads to get the spin lock using test_and_set_bit function of kernel. Can you provide me an example code to accomplish this. I am having a hard time compiling it.